# Haben vs aufhaben

Tags: usage, article

2 questions about this line from the dialog of a recent German Krimi Serie:

> "Bei einer Niederlage hat Kaminski Aussicht auf..."
> -- "Auf wie viel?"

1. How is the meaning changed by using **aufhaben** instead of just **haben**?
2. Is the use of **Aussicht** without an article grammatically correct, and if so, why? I would have written

> Bei einer Niederlage hat Kaminski **eine** Aussicht auf...

or

> Bei einer Niederlage hat Kaminski Aussicht**en** auf...

Comment: It’s not *aufhaben*, you omitted the object that *auf* refers to.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I see now. The next sentence continues this one: "Auf wie viel?" Any comment on the second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Aussicht auf etw. haben* is a fixed phrase meaning "having chances to get sth.", "having prospect of", *Aussicht* meaning "prospect" here, not "view". The phrase demands that it is actually plainly *Aussicht* (without the indetermined article *eine*).

So, the verb is actually *haben*, and not *aufhaben*, since *auf* is the preposition here, not a prefix of the verb.